# Unable to get values of querystring parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method written in my controller. I am passing values to this controller as querystring. The sample url to that controller method is:

window.location = "http://www.myapplication.org/Session/Enter?legacySessionId=fjD0pMTFTPFf6MgJZT0&RedirectPath=/Folio/OfflineDocument/EnqueueDocumentGenerationRequest/?FolderId=acf7egfsc0clz6ei&CourseId=vhvgyhgvhgvyy7yty"

My controller method has following definition:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Enter(
            string legacySessionId,
            string RedirectPath,
            string siteSubdomain = "",
            bool isDuplicate = false,
            int id = 0
        )
```

Inside this controller method when I get the querystring value for RedirectPath it only gives:

```
RedirectPath="/Folio/OfflineDocument/EnqueueDocumentGenerationRequest/?FolderId=acf7egfsc0clz6ei"
```

Whereas the expected result is :

```
RedirectPath="/Folio/OfflineDocument/EnqueueDocumentGenerationRequest/?FolderId=acf7egfsc0clz6ei&CourseId=vhvgyhgvhgvyy7yty"
```

It is missing "CourseId" part. Can someone point out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the ampersand char:

```
& ==> &amp;
```

To will be:

> `window.location = "http://www.myapplication.org/Session/Enter?legacySessionId=fjD0pMTFTPFf6MgJZT0&RedirectPath=/Folio/OfflineDocument/EnqueueDocumentGenerationRequest/?FolderId=acf7egfsc0clz6ei&amp;CourseId=vhvgyhgvhgvyy7yty"`

`&` is the separator of arguments in the url. If this char is part of the value, it has to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape ampersand in parameter. Just encode that parameter value.

```
window.location = "http://localhost:13203/Home/Enter?legacySessionId=fjD0pMTFTPFf6MgJZT0&RedirectPath=" 
                  + encodeURIComponent("/Folio/OfflineDocument/EnqueueDocumentGenerationRequest/?FolderId=acf7egfsc0clz6ei&CourseId=vhvgyhgvhgvyy7yty");
```